# Why do I get "0.0" returned to me every time in this situation?

Tags: java, oop, output

Here is my "UserNumber" object I have created in order to store the value the user gives me:

```
public class UserNumber 
{

    public double userNumber;

    public double getNumber()
    {
        return userNumber;
    }

    public void setNumber(double n)
    {
        userNumber = n;
    }

    public void printNumber()
    {
        System.out.println(userNumber);
    }
}
```

Here is my class that gets the input and (for testing purposes) spits the number back out:

```
public class GetInput 
{
    public void getInput()
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter any number that could be stored in      a double");
        double number = input.nextDouble();

        UserNumber setNum = new UserNumber();
        setNum.setNumber(number);



        UserNumber showAns = new UserNumber();
        showAns.printNumber();

        input.close();
   }
}
```

Every single time I run this I input stuff like 10.6004 or 2.0 etc...and it always gives me "0.0."

TIA.

Comment: Think of `setNum` and `showAns` as boxes. You've put your number into the `getNum` box, but you're trying to get it out of the `showAns` box. It's not there. It's still in the `getNum` box where you put it.

Comment: You have created 2 different UserNumber instances, with two different locations holding a double (one inside of each).  You are setting the first instance, then asking the second one for the value.  It isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are creating new instance of `UserNumber` and then calling `printNumber` from the new instance so `double userNumber` is `0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a second `showAns` instance? You need to use the instance of the object for which you set the correct input number.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter any number that could be stored in      a double");
double number = input.nextDouble();

UserNumber setNum = new UserNumber();
setNum.setNumber(number);

// UserNumber showAns = new UserNumber(); don't create another instance
setNum.printNumber(); // use the existing one where you set the double

input.close();
```

You are always getting `0.0` since it is the default value for a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

You create new instance of `UserNumber` called `showAns`, and use it to print. But the problem is that the value inputed by the user is stored in the `setNum` object and `showAns` is zero. Use `setNum` to print the result.

Also a tip, `double UserNumber` should be private, it breaks the encapsulation and there is no reason whatsoever for it to be public since you have public getter in the class.

Comment: I will set it back to private, I just made everything public in order to see if encapulation had anything to do with my problem!